# HTML multiple ul>li traverse back and forth using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to traverse multiple lists using Next / Previous buttons.
My method works for a single list. I'm failing at finding the ids for lists below or above the initially selected list. What jquery method I must use? I'm posting below my sample code and hope it'll make sense.

I tried .parent().next() no success.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>List</title>
  <style>
  .selected_bkg {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="prv">Prev</button><button id="next">Next</button>
<div id="liid" hidden>1a</div>
<div id="uls">
    <div class="">Category Fruits</div>
    <ul>
      <li class="lis selected_bkg" id="1a">Orange</li>
      <li class="lis" id="2a">Apple</li>
      <li class="lis" id="3a">Pear</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="">Category Vegitables</div>
    <ul>
      <li class="lis" id="1b">Carrot</li>
      <li class="lis" id="2b">Cabbage</li>
      <li class="lis" id="3b">Brocoli</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="">Category Meat</div>
    <ul>
      <li class="lis" id="1c">Beef</li>
      <li class="lis" id="2c">Chicken</li>
      <li class="lis" id="3c">Mutton</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<script>
$('#next').click(function() {
    lid=$('#liid').text()
    $('#'+lid).toggleClass('selected_bkg')
    nxtid=$('#'+lid).next('.lis').attr('id')
    if(typeof nxtid == 'undefined') {
        nxtid=$('#'+lid).parent().next('.lis').attr('id')
    }
    $('#'+nxtid).toggleClass('selected_bkg')
    console.log(lid, nxtid, '-',$('#'+nxtid).text(),'-')
    $('#liid').text(nxtid)
});
$('#prv').click(function() {
    lid=$('#liid').text()
    $('#'+lid).toggleClass('selected_bkg')
    nxtid=$('#'+lid).prev('.lis').attr('id')
    if(typeof nxtid == 'undefined') {
        nxtid=$('#'+lid).parent().prev('.lis').attr('id')
    }
    $('#'+nxtid).toggleClass('selected_bkg')
    console.log(lid, nxtid, '-',$('#'+nxtid).text(),'-')
    $('#liid').text(nxtid)
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet that does the trick - looping through list items, and not paying attention to "where they are".

```js
$('#next').on('click', function() {
  nextPrev(1)
})

$('#prv').on('click', function() {
  nextPrev(-1)
})

// this function handles the prv and next button clicks
// by using the dir (direction) parameter, that can be
// 1 (one) or -1 (negative one)
function nextPrev(dir) {
  let index = 0

  // iterating over the items, so we can find the index of
  // the selected item in the list of the selector items
  $('.lis').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).hasClass('selected_bkg')) {
      index = i
    }
  })

  // handling class changes (removing class and adding class
  // to previous or next item)
  if ((index + (1 * dir) >= 0) && (index + (1 * dir) < $('.lis').length)) {
    $($('.lis')[index]).removeClass('selected_bkg')
    $($('.lis')[index + (1 * dir)]).addClass('selected_bkg')
  }
}
```

```css
.selected_bkg {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<button id="prv">Prev</button><button id="next">Next</button>
<div id="liid" hidden>1a</div>
<div id="uls">
  <div class="">Category Fruits</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="lis selected_bkg" id="1a">Orange</li>
    <li class="lis" id="2a">Apple</li>
    <li class="lis" id="3a">Pear</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="">Category Vegitables</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="lis" id="1b">Carrot</li>
    <li class="lis" id="2b">Cabbage</li>
    <li class="lis" id="3b">Brocoli</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="">Category Meat</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="lis" id="1c">Beef</li>
    <li class="lis" id="2c">Chicken</li>
    <li class="lis" id="3c">Mutton</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The basic idea is that **jQuery** creates a list of objects through the selector. So `$('.lis')` is not only **ONE ELEMENT**, but all the elements that match this selector - but for ease of use it refers to the first element that is found when you just write it like that.

As a **jQuery object is actually a list**, you can iterate over it with **$.each()** and do your stuff element by element. So, you don't have to know where exactly the selected elements are in the DOM, only that they are selected by the selector.

The only thing that's missing from my snippet is that you can **prv** before the first element and **next** after the last - so you need to add "guards" to that.

## EDIT

I finished the "guards" - you cannot **prv** before item 1 or **next** past the last item.

Comment: Correct! I made changes to my code and works as expected. I too tried with .each() function arlier but discarded it since it traverse the entire ul lists. But now I see that it is the only way out.

Comment: In this case **$.each()** is more performant than DOM traversal - so you get two for the price of one :)